# Why do i have to click twice to open a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to make a button on which if we click a popup opens(modal) and it is working but only problem is i need to click it twice to open it and i don't see how can i solve it.

```js
// Get the modal
function modal1() {

  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn" onclick="modal1()">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you in advance :)
ps: I am leaning in very early stage js (beginner)

Comment: you can set counter and each time you click on button add 1 to counter and in your function if counter == 2 then do what you want in function

Comment: @MehranBeiglou it already does that but i dont need this to happen what i need is is that modal opens in first clicks but it already requires two click

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward if you read your code in order.

- When you click the button, it runs the `modal1()` function.
- This function, among other things, adds a `btn.onclick` listener, waiting for a click.

That's it.

So now, you have to click a second time in order to trigger the listener you just created.

The new `onclick` listener you create, for that matter, overrides the current `onclick` on the button, and I'm not sure why you do this.

The simple solution is to put `modal.style.display = "block"` directly in `modal1()`. Why override the `onclick` function?

```
function modal1() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```